# Yii2: How to set MySQL Locale

Tags: mysql, yii2

In one model I need to search dates as strings written in German language:

```
->andFilterWhere(['like', 'DATE_FORMAT(`date`,\'%d. %M %Y\')', $this->date])
```

Before the filter is applied, the locale has to be set with the following SQL command:

```
SET lc_time_names = 'de_DE';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple:

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SET lc_time_names = 'de_DE';")->execute();
```

The command can be tested:

```
$connection = Yii::$app->getDb();

$command = $connection->createCommand("SET lc_time_names = 'de_DE';");
$result = $command->execute();
var_dump($result);

$command = $connection->createCommand('SELECT @@lc_time_names;');
$result = $command->queryAll();
var_dump($result);

exit;
```

More info:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/locale-support.html
- http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
'db' => [
    // ...
    'on afterOpen' => function($event) {
        // $event->sender refers to the DB connection
        $event->sender->createCommand("SET lc_time_names = 'de_DE';")->execute();
    }
],
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-dao.html